# How to put data of MS excel of one column inside array in vb.net

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel

[image]

I have data on my MS.Excel spreadsheet which contain different column  (Sn , Amount and tech id). I am trying to put all the data of tech id on tech id in array like :-

```
  mydata = [43219 , 43220 , 43221 , 43222 ,43223 ,43224 , 43225 ]
```

My code of only one main processing function:-

Importing :-

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

main processing function:-

```
Dim conString1 As String
Dim Mydata(200) As Integer
Dim connection As OleDbConnection
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter

Private Sub LoadData(conStr As String)
    con = New OleDbConnection(conStr)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet0$]"
    adapter  = New oleDbDataAdapter(query, connection)

    'Putting data indide array
    'For intCount = 0 To lengthofcolumn 
          'Mydata(intCount) = ?
    'Next intCount

    Debug.Print(adapter)

End Sub
```

Calling :-

```
 conString1 = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '{0}'; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0", 'F:\MicroTest\data\log.xlsx)')
```

LoadData(conString1)

I am a student , I am learning so please help ,I did't find this solution , Mostly I found solution of viewing excel data in datagrid

Comment: probably the easiest thing to do there is instantiate a datatable and fill it from the adapter. `Dim dt as new datatable` and then `adapter.fill(dt)`. Now you have the results of your select in that table. You can then iterate through the table and get any of the information it holds. You really wouldn't even need it in an array at this point but could just as easily loop through and place that column into an array. Another option is that you could just `SELECT [Tech Id] From [Sheet0$]` which would be a datatable containing only those values.

Comment: Although .Net collections are zero based, Excel in not part of .Net. Unless you explicitly named the sheet Sheet0, the first sheet in a workbook is Sheet1 by default.

Answer (score 0):

My test data was in B2:B8.

You will need to add the Reference: Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library

```
    Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\test_data.xlsx")

    Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = oExcel.Sheets(1)

    ' I would use list instead of an array.
    Dim oTest As New List(Of String)
    For Each oValue As String In oSheet.Range("B2:B8").Value2
        oTest.Add(oValue)
    Next

    ' Using an array
    Dim oData(200) As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer = 0

    For Each oValue As String In oSheet.Range("B2:B8").Value2
        oData(iCounter) = CType(oValue, Integer)
        iCounter += 1
    Next

    oExcel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is good, accessing the file with OleDB and not openning an instance of Excel.
I used a DataReader and DataTable to collect and hold the data in memory.

The Using...End Using blocks ensure your objects that have a Dispose method are closed and disposed properly even if there is an error.

```
 Private Sub LoadData()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim conStr As String = "Your connection string"
            Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
                Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    con.Open()
                    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        dt.Load(dr)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            'The number of rows in the DataTable less the first 2 rows which are title and blank
            'and subtract 1 because vb.net arrays are defined array(upper bound)
            Dim arraySize As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 3
            Dim myData(arraySize) As Integer
            Dim arrayIndex As Integer = 0
            'Putting data indide array
            For rowIndex As Integer = 2 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                myData(arrayIndex) = CInt(dt.Rows(rowIndex)(3)) '3 is the index of the TechID column
                arrayIndex += 1
            Next
            'Checking the array - delete in final version
            'I used i as a variable name because this is a very tiny
            'loop and will be deleted eventually. Otherwise, I would
            'have used a more descriptive name.
            For Each i As Integer In myData
                Debug.Print(i.ToString)
            Next
        End Sub
```